# How do I use ObservableCollection<string> as a custom dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom dependency property of type ObservableCollection. I want to be able to add items to it from the code behind of XAML. But I can see that when I add items to it from ViewModel the binding gets updated but not when I add items to it from code behind. Is this not possible or am I missing something critical. Thanks in advance

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="NodeEditor.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NodeEditor.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:NodeEditor.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:ItemsList}"
        MouseDown="AddItems"
        ItemsList="{Binding ItemsList}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"></Rectangle>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Height="500" Width="500"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemListProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                      name: "ItemList",
                                                                      propertyType: typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
                                                                      ownerType: typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_OnLoaded;
        this.SetValue(ItemListProperty, new ObservableCollection<string>());
    }

    private void AddItems(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        this.ItemList.Add("newItem");
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new ItemsList();
        this.SetValue(ItemListProperty, new ObservableCollection<NodeClass>());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemList
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<string>)this.GetValue(ItemListProperty);
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ItemListProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ItemsList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _itemList;

    public ItemsList()
    {
        this._itemList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.ItemList = new ObservableCollection<string> { 
            "Item1","Item2"
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemList
    {
        get => this._itemList;
        set
        {
            this._itemList = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ItemList));
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why you have the dependency property in your Window. It serves no purpose at all. Remove it.

Comment: You would however have to write `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"` to bind to the ItemList property of the ItemsList view model object that is assigned to the DataContext of the Window. Also the `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>` in the ItemTemplate does not make any sense. The items are strings, which don't have a Name property.

Comment: Besides that the dependency property is redundant, `new ObservableCollection<NodeClass>()` is also not a valid value for a property of type `ObservableCollection<string>()`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a selection list so I can update the selected items from the view to the view model. Hence I need it to update the dependency property from the view. This is just a mockup that I thought would convey the idea. And the Node class in place of string was typo. However this works with non collection type properties.

Comment: If the items are provided by the view model, the selected items should also reside there. Add another collection property to your view model.

Comment: Basically creating a custom dependency property that has two way binding like text in a textbox, but for a collection type property

Comment: Your code won't compile. It would be helpful to post code that actually compiles. Otherwise, it is difficult to tell typos from the actual mistakes you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't compile. It would be helpful to post code that actually compiles. Otherwise, it is difficult to tell typos from the actual mistakes you made.

For example,

1. There is not `ItemsList` property defined on the `Window` type

   ```
   <!-- COMPILER ERROR! -->
   <Window ItemsList="{Binding ItemsList}"> </Window>
   ```
2. Your complete code does not define an Item_s_List, but ItemList (without the plural *s*). There is only a type Item_s_List but not such property.
3. The `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property is bound to an `Items` property which also doesn't exist!

   ```
   <!-- XAML DESIGNER ERROR! -->
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   ```
4. You can't assign a generic collection of type `NodeClass` to a generic collection of type `string`:

   ```
    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // COMPILER ERROR!
      this.SetValue(ItemListProperty, new ObservableCollection<NodeClass>());
    }
   ```

Now, after discussing your programming errors we can focus on the design errors.

> *"Basically creating a custom dependency property that has two way binding like text in a textbox, but for a collection type property"*

You generally don't have `TwoWay` bindings for collections because the binding target e.g. the `ItemsControl` does not change the property value, which would mean that it replaces the collection instance.
Instead, only the values in this collection are changed (at best -in a non MVVM application).

The main problem: your `MainWindow` and your view model class obviously work on different collection instances. That's why updating the collection from code-behind is not reflected in the view model. The instances must be the same. And there is more than one solution to realize this.

In fact, you are working with three different collection instances:

1. The dependency property has its own instance, set from the constructor:

   ```
   this.SetValue(ItemListProperty, new ObservableCollection<string>());
   ```

   Note that because of the CLR property wrappers you can write

   ```
   this.ItemList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   ```
2. The DataContext is returns second collection

   ```
    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Property is initialized with another/different instance
      this.DataContext = new ItemsList();
    }
   ```
3. Your view model class `ItemsList` provides the third  instance

   ```
    public ItemsList()
    {
      // This line is redundant as it is set from the property setter
      //this._itemList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

      // The third instance
      this.ItemList = new ObservableCollection<string> { 
        "Item1","Item2"
      };
    }
   ```

All collections must be the same instance if you want their changes to be reflected across different scopes.
For example, you can (and should) use the instance of the view model class `ItemsList`:

```cs
// Constructor of MainWindow
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  var viewModel = new ItemsList();
  this.DataContext = viewModel;

  // make this.ItemList return the same instance 
  // that is used in the ItemsList view model
  this.ItemList = viewModel.ItemList;

  // Now modifying this.ItemList will also modify ItemsList.ItemList
  this.ItemList.Add("newItem");

  viewModel.ItemList.Contains("newItem") // TRUE

  // However, the this.ItemList dependency property is redundant
  // because controls  should bind to the view model (this.DataContext)
  // and modifications can be made by referencing this view model instance.
  // Optionally, this view model instance can be stored 
  // in a private field to avoid the following casting:
  ((ItemsList)this.DataContext).ItemList.Add("newItem");
}
```

```xml
<!-- Bind to the DataContext (the ItemsList view model class) -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"> </ItemsControl>
```

These changes are meant to highlight your mistakes and not as the final solution.

However, they don't highlight the mistakes in terms of MVVM.
In an MVVM application, and based on the terminology that is used (like "view model") I assume you are implementing MVVM, the view is not allowed to manipulate data. The view only presents data.

---

In MVVM data manipulation takes place in the view model, either explicitly or implicitly via data binding.

The correct MVVM solution could look as follows:

**ItemsList.cs**
The view model is responsible to modify the data source collection.
For simplicity, this example does not use an `ICommand` to trigger the update operation. Commands are not required, but can simpliy the implementation.

```cs
class ItemsList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  
  private ObservableCollection<string> itemList;
  public ObservableCollection<string> ItemList
  {
    get => this.itemList;
    set
    {
      this.itemList = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.ItemList));
    }
  }

  public ItemsList()
  {
    // To guard against design violations, consider to define 
    // ItemList of type ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>.
    // This ensures that only the owner can modify the collection (and e.g., not the view)
    this.ItemList = new ObservableCollection<string> 
    {
      "Item1",
      "Item2"
    };
  }

  public void AddNewItem()
    => this.ItemList.Add("newItem");

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private ItemsList mainViewModel;

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.mainViewModel = new ItemsList();
    this.DataContext = this.mainViewModel;
  }

  private void OnAddNewItemButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.mainViewModel.AddNewItem();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="New item"
            Click="OnAddNewItemButtonClicked" />

    <!-- Bind to the DataContext (the view model class) -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource=²{Binding ItemList}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```